# JS Resource Calling root directory URL

Tags: url, permissions, resources, server

Some of the functionality from eFront CMS is not working because the files are being called wrong.

Console log:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Failed to load: http://efront.sageenvironmental.com/www/editor/tiny_mce_new/plugins/autolink/editor_plugin.js
```

**Should be calling:** www/editor/tiny_mce_new/plugins/autolink/editor_plugin.js

**But instead calling:** http://efront.sage.com/www/editor/tiny_mce_new/plugins/autolink/editor_plugin.js

I tried changing the permissions to allow access to the directory in the server, but it still is pulling the root url.

What can I do to get the resource to be called correctly and not add the home url in front.

Comment: You need to attach your code.  But it looks like you are trying to make an HREF, and it's adding IN the full URL because you left it out.  You should probably try calling the full URL yourself.

Comment: @durbnpoisn It is through the platform eFront, so its a packaged CMS. So I do not have direct access to the code and change the href. It is calling to a folder in the directory, but I think the permissions are preventing it from reaching the js file.

Comment: If you can't access the code, I doubt you can access the permissions.  In any case, you kinda left out the whole CMS thing in you original post.  Without better information, I don't think we can help.